# Send JSON, multipart/form-data via HTTPS POST to url (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, http-post

I want to send JSON, multipart-data via HTTPS POST to webservice-url in `C#`.

JSON:

```
info  = {
  fullname:"Name sername",
  code:"123465",
  code2:"12346",
  code3:"1234567"
}
```

How to send it to url in `C#`?

Comment: Create an `HttpClient` and construct a request to the URL

Comment: add to query string params

Comment: Why don't you just google it ?

Comment: What's the issue though? Is there something wrong with HTTPS?

Comment: I am new int C#. Not got result in Google. Thanks

Comment: i have wrote an answer help yourself

Comment: There are many ways of doing request, but the simplest probably is to follow this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request

Comment: is the answer working, accept it as an answer if it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ***example***.

```
public async Task<String> GetData()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Statics.Baseurl); 
        //The base Url is the Http Post request url (base) eg: http://www.example.com/
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        Info info = new Info();
        info.fullname = "Name surname";
        info.code = "123465";
        info.code2 = "123465";
        info.code3 = "123465";

        //JsonCOnvert.SerilizeObject() will convert your custom class to JSON
        StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(info), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        //the base address already defined in the client
        //This is the remaining part of the address.
        //We are passing the JSON value to the HTTP POST here.
        HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.PostAsync("api/Worker/GetDetails", content); 

        if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
             var response = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
             return response;
        }
        else
        {
             return "No_Data"; 
        }
     }
}
```

Here in the above example, there is a class `Info`, which can be defined as follows.

```
public class Info
{
   public String fullname { get; set; }
   public String code { get; set; }
   public String code2 { get; set; }
   public String code3 { get; set; }
}
```

**Note**:

1. `HttpClient` class can be found under `System.Net.Http` namespace
2. Use `RegisterAsyncTask` in your **asp.net web form** to trigger the `async` method. see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45) for more details.

Comment: Here I got some errors: " await client.PostAsync("api/Worker/GetDetails", content);"
The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: yes that is the basic of await operator. Use the code inside a method like public async Task<T> method_name() { ... }

Comment: I must replace the "api/Worker/GetDetails" to my api name?

Comment: How I can to call this "Task<String> GetData()" under the Button1_Click?

Comment: That is a method, it should not be under a button_click.

Comment: you should call the method, under the button_click

Answer (score -1):

Try this one it works.

```
var client = new RestClient("http://www.google.com");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "7ef33df4-9c36-4e92-9390-8fd17274d32d");
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=---- 
WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");

request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=---- 
WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", "------ 
WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
name=\"\"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", 
ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```